# List failing Elixir tests at the end of a run

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

Whenever there are multiple failures, I find it difficult to scroll through the verbose output and find the failing tests.

Is there a way to list all the failing tests at the end of a test suite run?

#### Actual

```
Finished in 12.9 seconds
2 doctests, 241 tests, 6 failures

Randomized with seed 793406
```

#### Expected

```
Finished in 12.9 seconds
2 doctests, 241 tests, 3 failures

- test/chat/foo/some_test.exs:111
- test/web/baz/another_test.exs:25
- test/api/yet_another_test.exs:58

Randomized with seed 793406
```

Comment: Not by default. You could write a custom ExUnit formatter that could do this. I'm pretty sure I remember other people asking about it in the past, so maybe the work is already done?